# Can I play or watch tennis with women as a professional tennis player?

Tags: halal-haram, zina, men-women

I'm a tennis player and I have to go out to several countries to play tennis. There are women with revealing clothes.

Can I see them without lusty eyes of course because of my work you know, some times the umpire is female and in hotel the receptionist is also female and etc but I heard the hadith that who ever see a non mahram on the day of qiyamat a rod of iron with lava put in ones eyes.

So does this mean that I can't talk to any women  even if it's because of my work and what is the ruling on touching or handshake without any lust.

In several countries girls are open minded  and if someone wins a match, he may need to shake hand with female umpire and sometime I need to practice with women, after practice we need to shake hand.

So what's the ruling on this am I doing a sin? can I watch women's matches while they wear mini skirts while playing as I'm not watching them but just watching the match without any evil thoughts.

Comment: There's a good answer which also alludes to the point I want to make: why would any Muslim choose professional sport as a job? Professional sport arguably qualifies as "laghw" in Islam which we should avoid. It is not constructive and a waste of time and resources. A Muslim would rather find a productive job that helps society.

Comment: Why man sports is a good thing it is not haraam even prophet mummahd(pbuh) also said to join a sports and prophet muhmmad(pbuh) also play sports of his time like archery and horse riding and many more there are also some  muslim professional football player out there so you can't say it's bad job it's very interesting

Comment: Just play with men. I mean most of the times men beat women easily. Not sure what the benefit is. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_the_Sexes_(tennis)

Comment: First, those sports that the Holy Prophet (pbuh) recommended weren't professional sports which you do for career. Second, he recommended them for their practical use: Muslims needed to know how to ride, swim and work with weapons like bows those days! Modern comparisons are knowing how to drive a car, operate a computer, or do martial art for self-defense in high-crime places.

Comment: So it doesn't mean that you can't take it as a career if the prophet (pbuh) play camel riding and archery because these are the sports of his time, now the time has changed you have in the time of prophet muhmmad (pbuh) there bussiness of different products  of their own time product so you can't say that today's bussiness man should not bussiness because you can't sell those 1400 years ago product, time changed brother so the sport are it doesn't matter whether you play football tennis archery or whatever the point is prophet pbuh told us to join the a sports so it's sports of our time.

Answer (score 5):

It has been said about this topic that if you can't find any other work to live on except this one (which I *assume* is not true in your case as it is known to exist in poor countries and those with great political conflicts), then you can stay in your work with avoiding the paths that lead to committing sins.

You mentioned that you exchange handshakes which is totally unpermitted in Islam:

It was narrated that Ma’qil ibn Yassaar said: the Messenger of Allaah (PBUH) said:

> For one of you to be stabbed in the head with an iron needle is better for him than that he should touch a woman who is not permissible for him.

Narrated by *al-Tabaraani in al-Kabeer, 486. Shaykh al-Albaani said in Saheeh al-Jaami’, 5045,* that this hadeeth is valid.

Moreover, I don't find the necessity of doing it. Why not skip that part by saying you are a Muslim? Most people know that Muslims don't shack hands with non-mahram women, so they will understand.

You also mentioned that you watch the match but not the girls who would be wearing revealing clothes. Even if you thought that you understand yourself better than anyone else by saying genuinely that you don't watch them with lust eyes, still, Allah knows you the best. Why wouldn't he when he is your creator, in the first place. Thus, if Allah ordered us to **avoid** the Shaitan footsteps as they eventually lead to disobedience, then who are we to say that that is not true?!

Surah Al-Baqarah (2) - Verse 168

In Arabic (the exact words):

> وَّ لَا تَتَّبِعُوۡا خُطُوٰتِ الشَّیۡطٰنِ ؕ اِنَّہٗ لَکُمۡ عَدُوٌّ مُّبِیۡنٌ...

The translation in English:

> …and do not follow the footsteps of the Shaitan; surely he is your open enemy.

I suggest you play with males-only teams and to not participate in competitions where would be girls teams participants.

---

For further reading about Shaytan paths: [See here](https://www.al-islam.org/the-heart-of-the-quran-commentary-of-sura-yasin-ayatullah-dastaghaib/ayat-no-60-63)

For further reading about shaking hands with non-Mahrams: [See here](https://www.google.ps/amp/s/islamqa.info/amp/en/answers/21183)

Comment: Thanks for your answer but what about talking to women you know on the receptionists is also women generally and ro services and many more so what about it @tasneem

Comment: Great question that I recommend you ask it separately. Let me know when you post it so I can provide an answer. And, you're welcome.

Comment: I've ask this question separately  you can now answer it brother @tasneem

Comment: I will. But it is always good to link related questions so they won't be misunderstood as duplicates besides the fact that they are related. [Your new question](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/55461/34139)