# Talking to a non mahram because of your work

Tags: halal-haram

Is it allowed to talking to a non mahram because of your work without any sexual intention or any evil thoughts I'm a tennis player I play tennis in a academy when I'm playing I don't talk to girls by myself they start conversation by calling me you know because they are open minded they don't care about what they are wearing they wear revealing clothes such as mini skirts etc  so I don't want to talk to them but they start taking if I don't talk it will be rude so I just talk without any sexual thought or any evil thoughts so is this a sin

Answer (score 1):

In such deals when you have to interact with the opposite gender, such as:

> - Making a deal between you and a seller/buyer.
> - Inquiring, for example, about the room rent from a recipient.
> - Talking to coworkers and colleagues because of work.
> - Working with your classmates in a school project.

are all **permitted** in Islam but **only** when it is totally **necessary** and/or **important**, and it has to be in the Islam limits and boundaries that have been set for such cases, like:

> - Don't laugh and smile to not give the wrong message and/or to ease their hearts.
> - Don't talk about unnecessary things, start new subjects, and discuss irrelevant matters.
> - Talk in what you came for and in a very formal way while being serious and tough.

Allah said (the exact wording in Arabic):

> فَلَا تَخْضَعْنَ بِالْقَوْلِ فَيَطْمَعَ الَّذِي فِي قَلْبِهِ مَرَضٌ وَقُلْنَ قَوْلًا مَعْرُوفًا...

The translation in English:

> If you fear Allah (is directed to women), then do not be soft in speech [to men], lest he in whose heart is disease should covet, but speak with appropriate speech.

Recited in this way:

> ... fa lā takhḍa'na bil-qauli fa yaṭma'allażī fī qalbihī maraḍuw wa qulna qaulam ma'rụfā

[*Surah Al-Ahzab (33) — Verse 32*](https://quran.com/33/32)

[Here's](https://youtu.be/KUh_6xSVeMQ) a funny yet informative Youtube video that talks about this topic.